# Adjusting font size of only text inside a div that contains both text and html

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my problem is i have a function that adjusts the font size of a div however this div contains both text and HTML so when the function runs, the nested HTML size also changes is there a way i can only change the size of the text and leave the HTML un touched ? any help is highly appreciated.. the code is in javascript

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with javascript but CSS. Your nested HTML is probably using 'em' as a unit. Since this is a unit relative to the current font-size it get affected when you change the font-size. This can be used as a feature but in your case it is unwanted. The easiest solution is to change the unit on your nested HTML to 'rem', it will then be relative to the root font-size which is not changing here or to the equivalent size in 'px' for example.